# How can i get the id of a polygon in an SVG file?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I created an SVG file (data/humanTest.svg):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.2.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 800 800" style="enable-background:new 0 0 800 800;" xml:space="preserve">

<polygon fill="yellow" id="forehead" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" points="318.1,24.6 308.7,40.3 308.7,79.6 360.6,82 378.6,46.6 370,8.9 346.4,17.5 "/>
</svg>
```

and i want to log the id "forehead" when i hover over the svg element but when i run my code i get null.

Here is my d3 code:

```
var main_chart_svg = d3.select("#diagram")
    .append("svg")
    .attr({
        "width": 800,
        "height": 800
    }).append('g');

 d3.xml("data/humanTest.svg").mimeType("image/svg+xml").get(function (error, xml) {
        if (error) throw error;

        var svgNode = xml
                .getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
        main_chart_svg.node().appendChild(svgNode);

        var innerSVG = main_chart_svg.select("svg");

        innerSVG.append("text")
            .attr("dy", "1em")
            .attr("dx", "1em")
            .text("Test text");

        innerSVG.on("mousemove", function (d) {

            //console.log(innerSVG.id);
            //d3.select("#diagram svg").selectAll("g")

            console.log(d3.select(this).attr('id')); //doesnt work,
            //gives me the svg id (Layer_1) not the id of the polygons within the svg tag

        })
    });
```

Would be very thankful if anyone could please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! What i did was i loaded the SVG into this: https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ and cleaned it up and made sure each  is on a single line.

Then i wrote a script to open this svg file, and reformat all the  lines to JSON.

Code:

```
OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.DefaultExt = "*.csv";
        dlg.Filter = "SVG Files (*.svg)|*.svg|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        DialogResult res = dlg.ShowDialog();
        if (res == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtSource.Text = dlg.FileName; //Textbox to show filepath
        }

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(txtSource.Text.Trim(), Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            string line;
            int ids = 1;
            StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
            json.Append("{\"Polygons\": [");

            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] s = { };
                string[] t = { };
                string[] v = { };
                StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder();

                try
                {
                    if (line.Trim().StartsWith("<poly"))
                    {
                        s = line.Split(new[] { "points=" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                        t = s[1].Split('/');
                        string points = t[0].Replace("\"", "").Trim();

                        v = points.Split(' ');
                        foreach (string xy in v)
                        {
                            string[] z = { };
                            z = xy.Split(',');
                            test.Append("{\"x\":" + z[0].ToString() + ", \"y\":" + z[1].ToString() + "},");
                        }

                        //Found the polygon line
                        json.Append("{\"name\": \"polyId_" + ids + "\",");
                        json.Append("\"points\":[");
                        json.Append(test.ToString().TrimEnd(','));
                        json.Append("]},");
                        ids++;
                    }
                }
                catch { json.Append(line + " ERROR <br/>"); }
            }
        }
```

Then i pasted the output into a .json file and loaded it. Then i adjusted my d3 script to simply get d.name

```
svg.selectAll("polygon").on("mousemove", function (d) {
                Ctooltip.attr("style", "left:420px;top:0px").html(d.name);
                //console.log(d.name);
            })
```

So the best way to do this was to avoid using the svg file exported from illustrator but to convert it to json and use that.

Answer (score 1):

Your `innerSVG` is the entire SVG. It doesn't have an ID named "forehead". In your code, `this` refers to the SVG element.

If you have only one polygon, use this instead:

```
console.log(d3.select("polygon").attr('id'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i only gave one polygon as an example. Your code works but only for one polygon, how can i modify it for multiple polygons so it can pick up the polygon that the mouse is hovering on?